# radiobutton set layoutparams do not work when be add to radiogroup

Tags: android, layoutparams

```
 val param =  LinearLayout.LayoutParams(WRAP_CONTENT,WRAP_CONTENT)
        param.rightMargin = 100

        val rb = RadioButton(this)
        rb.text = "1"
        rb.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"))
        rb.layoutParams = param

        rgroup.addView(rb)

        val rb2 = RadioButton(this)
        rb2.text = "2"
        rb2.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"))
        rb2.layoutParams = param
        rgroup.addView(rb2)
```

first  set layoutparams for  rb and then  add it to radiogroup , the right margin do no work when run in android M , but works over M ，its cause by diff andoird version  ? the same code , the diff result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `RadioGroup.LayoutParams` instead of `LinearLayout.LayoutParams`

Comment: yeah , it works , emm , but  what im wonder is why ```LinearLayout.LayoutParams ``` has no effect in M ,  is version difference ?

Comment: You must use the parent layout’s LayoutParams when setting params. Can’t say why it wasn’t working for you in M. Also please mark the answer as accepted if it has solved your problem.